# Jersey NoSuchMethodError Maven

Tags: java, maven, jersey, websphere-liberty

I had this problem while running my jersey application on ibm liberty java

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.&lt;init&gt;(ApplicationHandler.java:330)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.&lt;init&gt;(WebComponent.java:339)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:362)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>br.com.teste</groupId>
<artifactId>TesteApi</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.wasdev.wlp.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>liberty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
        <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.19</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
        <version>2.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160810</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-property-utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.pacesys</groupId>
        <artifactId>openstack4j</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.commons.io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.24</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mailjet</groupId>
        <artifactId>mailjet-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jhades</groupId>
        <artifactId>jhades</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I tried running Jhades to try to see what the incompatibility of classload was and I had this result

```
file:/C:/Desenvolvimento/Projetos/V2/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/TesteApi/WEB-INF/lib/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar overlaps with
file:/C:/Desenvolvimento/Projetos/V2/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/TesteApi/WEB-INF/lib/jsr250-api-1.0.jar - total overlapping classes: 11 - same classloader ! This is an ERROR!
```

I've already tried deleting javax.ws.rs-api from the jersey-container-servlet dependency because it is the only one that was getting javax.ws.rs-api. If anyone can help me, he was very grateful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please use [Maven Dependency Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/index.html) to get to know the details of incoming transitive dependencies -

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.0:tree
```

If its `javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api` that you don't want to let in as a transitive dependency as seen in the tree logs -

> ```
> > [INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.19:compile 
>
> > [INFO] |  +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
> ```

You can try adding the exclusion to the same as -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi, I posted below the list of my dependencies

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your dependencies, you'll see that the openstack dependencies the problem. It is pulling in `jaxrs-api` which is a jax-rs 1 jar. The jersey version are trying to use uses jax-rs two.you need to exclude the `jaxrs-api` jar from the openstack dependency and hopefully it doesn't break it. Or maybe there is a newer version of that depends dependency that uses jax-rs 2 (`jaxrs-api` 3.x.x).